# Probability of mutually exclusive distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

The following graph shows at what index number between 0 and 100 the underlying price is followed by a move up, down or whether there's no change.

**My question is as follows:**

How does one calculate the probability of each price move (or no move) occurring after a given index value? Each outcome is naturally mutually exclusive.

**Edit**

To clarify, let's assume the index value is 60 at a given time. Based on the historical data we know that when the index was at 60 in the past, the subsequent price move was up X number of times, down Y number of times and didn't change Z number of times. The question asks what the probability of X, Y and Z is at a given index value.

**End edit**

Intuitively, the number of observations of a given move at index point *X* must be calculated as a percentage of all observations before being compared to the rest, but that's as far as I can take it.

An intuitive as well as mathematical explanation of how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Also, the given graphs and data are just an example and I would assume non-essential to the method.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not understand this plot. What does the "index number" represent? One would think it is the index of a sequence, but then by the beginning of index 2 you would know the direction of the price move--but you list value that are much greater.  What data do you have?  What do they represent?  How were they obtained?

Comment: Fair point @whuber sorry for being unclear. The index is a relative strength index which shows the extent to which an asset or derivative is overbought or undersold. In this case it is relating to the price of oil on a minute by minute basis over a period of 3 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you have some variable $X$ that changes over time $t$. You are interested in probability of increase, or decrease (or no change) of the prices changes given the time index. To calculate empirical probability you simply need to calculate how often event such as $X_t > X_{t-1}$ occurred before or at time $t$ and divide by total number of all cases up to this moment (i.e. by $t$):

$$ \Pr(X_t > X_{t-1}|t) = \frac{\sum_{i=2}^t \mathbf{1}_{X_i > X_{i-1}}}{t} $$

where $\mathbf{1}_{X_i > X_{i-1}}$ is an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) that returns $1$ if $X_i > X_{i-1}$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim. I realise you answered before my edit which I hope clarified the question, but the index value as far as I know is not a time index, but an indicator based on an underlying time series. Please have a look at the edit and thanks for you time in answering!

Comment: @youjustreadthis if you ask about probability at a certain (discrete) point of time than it is simply: number of times event occurred by total number of events...